# Use installed a 3rd party file explorers. How do I get the register default explorer program via win32?

Tags: winapi

I guess it's like total commander or similar type program where they replace the default folder browser. How do I know via win32, what replacement program the user is used instead of explorer.exe

Answer (score 0):

There's no officially supported mechanism in Windows for changing the default folder browser.
However anything that does "replace Explorer" has to set itself as the default action for the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder key, so I would start by looking there.